# inheriting from FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am trying to subclass the FileSystemWatcher to intercept the Created event and delay it until I am able to get a handle on the file.  Typical scenario.  Am I wrong or there is no way of doing this without introducing my own SafeCreated event?  Meaning I don't see a way to override the OnCreated method that is responsible for raising the Created event.  Without overriding it I only have the event itself at my disposal, which is no good because the outside world could simply subscribe to that event as well.  What am I missing?

Either I'm missing something or I need to be going down the composition route as opposed to inheritance.

Comment: It needs to be `protected virtual` to be overrideable.

Comment: @Femaref, you're right, I wasn't thinking straight. Time to get some sleep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use composition as you can't override the method. However, getting access to the file isn't in the feature scope of the `FileSystemWacher`, it just monitors changes. Take care of the getting the handle in your own code.

Comment: Understood, that's why I wanted to subclass it to add that "feature" into it :)  I guess I'm not going crazy after all, I'll use composition.

Comment: The event wouldn't be the right place for it. Think about it - to detect if you got the handle, you need to take it and immediately release it. If you don't, none of the event's subscribers can act on the event as you have the handle yourself. If you release it, someone else unrelated to your code can get the handle in the meantime, thus rendering all your efforts useless. The place for your code really is the code that **acts** on the event, not the event itself.

Comment: I guess I should have elaborated more.  My intention was to override the method, and throw the exclusive locking check on the ThreadPool.  When the exclusive lock is obtained I would have raised the Created event myself from that ThreadPool thread.